# android Sherlock ActionBar kills resources

Tags: android, resources, actionbarsherlock

I want to implement `Sherlock ActionBar` for compatibility. Everything seems to be fine, but Eclipse returns errors in every line that has a resource path - `R.id.###`, `R.string.###`, etc.

Did you, who used Sherlock, experienced such problems? How did you solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your imports, make sure that you are using the correct R class (not android.R for example).

Comment: i tried both eclipse suggestions `import android.R` and `import com.actionbarsherlock.R`, but then values still are not found (ex. R.id.viewpager)

Comment: Try cleaning your projects. There's no need to import any of these, the right R class is in your package.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you're building for Android 4.0 or higher (Properties|Android|Project Build Target). You can run the project on Android 2.x nevertheless then.